# Android: get the amount of bytes transferred by MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

As the title says, I need to get the amount of bytes downloaded/uploaded by MapView?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot tell specifically for `MapView`. You can tell the data transfer for your whole app via `TrafficStats`.